# How to see error logging done by Oracle's DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE Utility ?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

I'm running a procedure in parallel by using oracle's dbms parallel execute utility which chunks the workload ; but I have few chunks failing and I can't see any error logs. Is there a way to find out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this. The last two columns.

```
   SELECT *
        FROM   user_parallel_execute_chunks
        WHERE  task_name = '{task name}'
        ORDER BY chunk_id
    /
```

I'm not sure, but probably you can use job_name from previous table. And query  for more information from scheduler's tables. `user_scheduler_job_run_details`, `user_scheduler_job_log`.